# web3js/nodejs error: eth.sendTransaction invalid address

Tags: web3js

I want to invoke a send transaction from my nodejs code using web3js api. But I'm getting error at eth.sendTransaction step: **invalid address**.
I have added default account assignment after looking at some other posts. But still the same error.
Any clue?

```
bcConn.eth.defaultAccount = bcConn.eth.accounts[0];
var defaultFlag = bcConn.personal.unlockAccount(bcConn.eth.accounts[0], '***whatever***', 15000);
if (defaultFlag) {

    var unlockFlag = bcConn.personal.unlockAccount(fromAddress, passphrase, 15000);
    if (unlockFlag) {

        **bcConn.eth.sendTransaction(fromAddress, toAddress, passphrase, sendAmount, function (err, result)** {
            if (err) return next(err, null);
            return next(null, result);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('DAO unlock error: ' +err);
        return next(err, null);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) method has only a json param, so i modified it, as follows:

```
bcConn.eth.defaultAccount = bcConn.eth.accounts[0];
var defaultFlag = bcConn.personal.unlockAccount(bcConn.eth.accounts[0], '***whatever***', 15000);
if (defaultFlag) {

    var unlockFlag = bcConn.personal.unlockAccount(fromAddress, passphrase, 15000);
    if (unlockFlag) {

        **bcConn.eth.sendTransaction({from:fromAddress,to:toAddress,value:sendAmount}, function (err, result)** {
            if (err) return next(err, null);
            return next(null, result);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('DAO unlock error: ' +err);
        return next(err, null);        
    }
}
```

Hope it works~

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying an object rather than a list of arguments to `sendTransaction`:

```
bcConn.eth.sendTransaction({from:fromAddress, to:toAddress, value:sendAmount}, function (err, result){...})
```

Note that I've removed `passphrase` here - it's not needed.